# Chinese Remainder Theorem Problem and the Ring Z(p)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

so I have this problem and I'm running into some issues with it. Suppose we have the following system of equations -

$$-1 \equiv (x\times y)~ mod ~(z)$$
$$-1 \equiv (x\times z)~ mod ~(y)$$
$$-1 \equiv (y\times z)~ mod ~(x)$$

I'd like to find integer solutions to this equation. Are there any at all? How to tell?
This system of congruences appears to conform to a Chinese remainder theorem type of question, where it would then follow that -

$$-1 \equiv [\sum(a_i~\times~b_i~\times~\frac{M}{m_i})]~ mod ~M$$

As can be found here -
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

The question is in the detail of the formulation of the solution. Since $x, y, z$ are arbitrary, how to find their multiplicative inverses in some modular class? I.e. How to find the multiplicative inverse of $(x\times y) ~mod ~z$? Named in wolfram's formulation $b_i$. Another point is that if you notice, in the summands, we multiply by $M$ and then take the entire sum $mod ~M$. Wouldn't the sum be congruent to $0$ in that case?

2. One result the professor has been alluding to the entire semester, is the fact that if a statement is true in **Z**, then it is true in **Z**(p) for any prime p. This seems to make sense, since the primes generate the integers. However, could someone point me to the formal statement of that theorem?

Comment: If a polynomial equation with integer coefficients has a solution in integers, then it has a solution mod $m$ for every $m$,  "Statement" is too general.

Comment: would you write your system of equations as separate sentences with punctuation so we can make sense of it?

Answer (score 1):

An example, how inverses are found.

Assume, $28$ has to be inverted modulo $33$

The calculation of the gcd

$$33=1\times 28+5$$

$$28=5\times 5+3$$

$$5=1\times 3+2$$

$$3=1\times 2+1$$

can be worked backwards leading to

$$1=3-2=3-(5-3)=2\times 3-5=2\times(28-5\times5)-5=2\times 28-11\times 5$$

$$=2\times 28-11\times(33-28)=13\times 28-11\times 33$$

So, $28^{-1}\equiv 13\ (\ mod\ 33\ )$

If the equation would be $1=(-10)\times 28+4\times 33$ (which is of course not the case, but I want to explain how to deal with negative multiplicators), for instance, we would have $28^{-1}\equiv 33-10=23\ (\ mod\ 33\ )$

Comment: Hm, thanks. But even still, when x, y, z are arbitrary, I cannot use this algorithm. For one thing, I cannot determine the base case for when the remainder is = 1.